# QWebView call Javascript function

Tags: javascript, qt, user-interface, webview

I try to connect signal triggered() of QAction with JS function in QWebView.
So, my code:

```
...      
QWebView *webView = new QWebView;   
QAction *buttonAction = new QAction;
webView->load(QUrl(":/example.html");
...   
connect(buttonAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(alert()));  
...
```

Slot function:

```
void MainWindow::alert()
{
   webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(QString("myFunction();"));
}
```

In example.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
       alert("I am an alert box!");
    }
</script>
```

So, application starts normal, but when I'm pressing button, application falls with error, instead of displaying alert. Also, there is message in debug:

```
QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting
```

What is the matter?

Comment: What is the QAction tied to? update the alert slot in your MainWindow with just QMessageBox::information(this, "Test", "Test"); and see if the crash still happens. You can also drop the semi-colon in the JavaScript function call. You can just have it as webView->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("myFunction()");

Comment: @Viv With QMessageBox button works fine, no crashes.  Dropping semi-colon in JS function call doesn't help.

Comment: I think, crash is tied with "QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting". But I have no idea how to fix it.